# Sort Ruby Hash by order in array of keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
sample = { bar: 200, foo: 100, baz: 100 }
```

How do I sort `sample` using the order of keys in `sort_order`:

```
sort_order = [:foo, :bar, :baz, :qux, :quux]
```

Expected result:

```
sample #=> { foo: 100, bar: 200, baz: 100 }
```

All I can come up with is

```
new_hash = {}
sort_order.each{|k| new_hash[k] = sample[k] unless sample[k].nil? }
sample = new_hash
```

There's got to be a better way. Hints?

Keys without values should not be present, i.e. number of keys remain the same, which isn't the case with [Sort Hash Keys based on order of same keys in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302058/sort-hash-keys-based-on-order-of-same-keys-in-array)

Comment: What do you want in a better way? Shorter? Better performance?

Comment: 1. Shorter
2. Better performance
In that order

Comment: @Amit How is this different from my solution?

Comment: `sample.sort_by { |k,_| sort_order.index(k) }.to_h` or `sort_order.each_with_object({}) { |sym,h| h[sym] = sample[sym] if sample.key?(sym) }`.

Comment: Could there be keys in `sample` that do not exist in `sort_order`?

Comment: Are you in a Rails project? Active_support's `slice` provides the most concise implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A functional approach using the intersection of keys:

```
new_sample = (sort_order & sample.keys).map { |k| [k, sample[k]] }.to_h
#=> {:foo=>100, :bar=>200, :baz=>100}
```

As @Stefan noted, the abstraction [Hash#slice](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveSupport%2FCoreExtensions%2FHash%2FSlice%3Aslice!) from ActiveSupport's pretty much does the job:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
new_sample = sample.slice(*sort_order)
#=> {:foo=>100, :bar=>200, :baz=>100}
```

Comment: `slice` checks if the keys exist (similar to [Keith Bennett's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37405469/477037)), so you can just write `sample.slice(*sort_order)`

Answer (score 3):

The code below does this.  Note that I used [`has_key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) because you want the output hash to contain all the keys in the input hash, even if their values are `nil`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def sorted_hash(input_hash, key_sort_order)
  new_hash = {}
  key_sort_order.each do |key|
    if input_hash.has_key?(key)
      new_hash[key] = input_hash[key]
    end
  end
  new_hash
end

sort_order = [:foo, :bar, :baz, :qux, :quux]
sample = { bar: 200, foo: 100, baz: 100 }

puts sorted_hash(sample, sort_order)
# Outputs: {:foo=>100, :bar=>200, :baz=>100}
```

A simplification is to use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def sorted_hash_two(input_hash, key_sort_order)
  key_sort_order.each_with_object({}) do |key, result_hash|
    if input_hash.has_key?(key)
      result_hash[key] = input_hash[key]
    end
  end
end

puts sorted_hash_two(sample, sort_order)
# Outputs: {:foo=>100, :bar=>200, :baz=>100}
```

I like @tokland's idea of array intersection (`&`) better because it elmiinates the need for an `if` condition:

```
def sorted_hash_ewo_intersection(input_hash, key_sort_order)
  (key_sort_order & input_hash.keys).each_with_object({}) do |key, result_hash|
    result_hash[key] = input_hash[key]
  end
end # produces: {:foo=>100, :bar=>200, :baz=>100}
```

Comment: The ```each_with_object``` looks simpler, however, I don't see how its any better than my solution.

Comment: As I mention in the answer, I think it's important to use `has_key?` rather than test for nil.  As an aside, I recommend expressing this as a method; that separates the logic in question from the inputs and outputs; and your last name `sample = new_hash` is unnecessary.

Comment: I just added @tokland's approach of using array intersection (using `&`) but using `each_with_object`, and like that one the best.

Comment: Note that `&` is really set intersection; if there were duplicates then those duplicates would be stripped, e.g.: [1] & [1,1] => [1] and [1,1] & [1] => [1]. In this case, both arrays are guaranteed not to have duplicates since hash keys are always unique, but it's something to be aware of in other contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Please, see my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36302523/4739257):

```
sort_order = [:foo, :bar, :baz, :qux, :quux, :corge, :grault,
              :garply, :waldo, :fred, :plugh, :xyzzy, :thud]
sample = { bar: 200, foo: 100, baz: 100 }

sample.sort_by {|k, _| sort_order.index(k)}.to_h
=> {:foo=>100, :bar=>200, :baz=>100}
```

Comment: Not a problem for small inputs, but note that this is quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way this can be done:

```
(sort_order & sample.keys).zip([nil]).to_h.merge(sample)
#=> {:foo=>100, :bar=>200, :baz=>100}
```

---

**Explanation:**

First we create a hash that contains only desired keys in the right order.

```
(sort_order & sample.keys).zip([nil]).to_h
#=> {:foo=>nil, :bar=>nil, :baz=>nil}
```

And then, we merge this hash with `sample` to get the values from `sample`.

Comment: Sorry, please forget about my comments that I have deleted.